# Robust PHP Image Upload

Tags: image, upload

I'm building part of a solution that handles image uploads (in PHP) - and I've done some reading about, there are a huge number of ways in which exploits can be found, and I'd like to protect against all of them.

With that in mind, what is the most robust method of validating image uploads and ensuring they are safe (/can't do any server damage?). Storing the images outside of a HTTP accessible area is unfortunately not possible because its a shared host.

The images will be sent to the server via a post form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you are right you have to check the uploaded image whether it is image or any script that damage to server.

For that purpose you can check **Header information of image** 
whether it is valid image or not.

If it is valid image then do further process.

For that purpose you can also check 'exif information '.